# boot.img too large when i compile twrp

Tags: android

I'm trying to compile twrp for my device,but I met some errors and I can't
solve it. Can someone help?

This is error:

> /home/hsl/cm12/out/target/product/nx511j/boot.img maxsize=3514368
>   blocksize=135168 total=17790976 reserve=270336 error:
>   /home/hsl/cm12/out/target/product/nx511j/boot.img too large (17790976
>
> > [3784704 - 270336]) make: *** [/home/hsl/cm12/out/target/product/nx511j/boot.img] 错误 1 make: ***
> >     正在删除文件“/home/hsl/cm12/out/target/product/nx511j/boot.img” make: ***
> >     正在等待未完成的任务....

## BoardConfig.mk

```
fix this up by examining /proc/mtd on a running device
BOARD_BOOTIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x00380000
BOARD_RECOVERYIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x00480000
BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x08c60000
BOARD_USERDATAIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x105c0000
BOARD_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE := 131072
```

## something I found about Boot & Recovery Partitions

major minor  #blocks  name

```
179        0   15392768 mmcblk0

179        1      65536 mmcblk0p1

179        2         32 mmcblk0p2

179        3       1536 mmcblk0p3

179        4         16 mmcblk0p4

179        5          1 mmcblk0p5

179        6          8 mmcblk0p6

179        7        512 mmcblk0p7

179        8        512 mmcblk0p8

179        9       1024 mmcblk0p9

179       10       1024 mmcblk0p10

179       11        512 mmcblk0p11

179       12        512 mmcblk0p12

179       13        512 mmcblk0p13

179       14        512 mmcblk0p14

179       15        512 mmcblk0p15

179       16        512 mmcblk0p16

179       17       1536 mmcblk0p17

179       18       1536 mmcblk0p18

179       19      32768 mmcblk0p19

179       20      32768 mmcblk0p20

179       21      32768 mmcblk0p21

179       22    1572864 mmcblk0p22

179       23       8192 mmcblk0p23

179       24     262144 mmcblk0p24

179       25       1024 mmcblk0p25

179       26        512 mmcblk0p26

179       27         32 mmcblk0p27

179       28      65536 mmcblk0p28

179       29      10240 mmcblk0p29

179       30   12947919 mmcblk0p30

179       32       4096 mmcblk0rpmb

179       64   15558144 mmcblk1

179       65   15556608 mmcblk1p1
```

---

```
1970-01-01 15:14 DDR -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2

1970-01-01 15:14 aboot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9

1970-01-01 15:14 abootbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10

1970-01-01 15:14 boot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p19

1970-01-01 15:14 cache -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p24

1970-01-01 15:14 config -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p27

1970-01-01 15:14 fsc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5

1970-01-01 15:14 fsg -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3

1970-01-01 15:14 hyp -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15

1970-01-01 15:14 hypbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16

1970-01-01 15:14 keystore -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p26

1970-01-01 15:14 misc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p25

1970-01-01 15:14 modem -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1

1970-01-01 15:14 modemst1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p17

1970-01-01 15:14 modemst2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p18

1970-01-01 15:14 oem -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p28

1970-01-01 15:14 persist -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p23

1970-01-01 15:14 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20

1970-01-01 15:14 recovery2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p21

1970-01-01 15:14 rpm -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11

1970-01-01 15:14 rpmbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12

1970-01-01 15:14 sbl1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7

1970-01-01 15:14 sbl1bak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8

1970-01-01 15:14 sec -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4

1970-01-01 15:14 splash -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p29

1970-01-01 15:14 ssd -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6

1970-01-01 15:14 system -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22

1970-01-01 15:14 tz -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13

1970-01-01 15:14 tzbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14

1970-01-01 15:14 userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p30
```

Answer (score 3):

Necro-Answering as I was looking for the same info for the Nubia Z11 mini :)

You have the info needed in your post to calculate it.

However, to make the answer complete in order for others to get the info from adb you posted, one can do this (assumes you are rooted).

```
adb shell
su
cd /dev
ls -lR|grep by-name|grep block
```

For me this outputs `./block/platform/7824900.sdhci/by-name:`. Unless you have busybox/toybox installed you can't cut off the end colon using a command so you have to copy and paste it manually like a chump and then do:

```
ls -l ./block/platform/7824900.sdhci/by-name|grep recovery
```

For me this outputs

```
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1970-06-22 19:11 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22
```

For you it would have output `1970-01-01 15:14 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20`

The key part is the word at the end. You then get the number of blocks for that.

```
cat /proc/partitions|grep mmcblk0p20
```

For you this will have output

```
179       20      32768 mmcblk0p20
```

This says there are 32768 blocks.

Each block is 1024 in size.

```
32768 x 1024 = 33554432
```

Therefore in your BoardConfig.mk you put

```
# Partitions
BOARD_BOOTIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 33554432
BOARD_RECOVERYIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 33554432
```

A search on GitHub for this phone and BoardConfig.mk show that the calculations match what other people are using.

https://github.com/nx511j-multirom/android_device_nubia_nx511j/blob/mkm/BoardConfig.mk#L70-L71